# Is it possible to create a linked table in MS - Access from an Excel spreadsheet located on OneDrive or Google Drive

Tags: ms-access

I am using AppSheet to create an application that stores info in a spreadsheet that comes from either Google Drive or OneDrive. I would like to link this spreadsheet to an Access database.

**Is that possible?**

Comment: What kind of Access database?

Answer (score 0):

If you have GDrive or Onedrive installed on your pc, the Excel sheet should be synced on your pc, and you should be able to link to the local copy.